# Ошибка Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range при попытке посчитать количество букв в строке

Tags: java, netbeans

Написал код,который должен был считать количество букв w в строке,но все падает с ошибкой.
Проверил отладчиком,код выполняется нормально,до последней проверки,а после выдает ошибку

Код:

```
String s="www.oracle.com";

        int lenght=s.length();

        int index=0;

        int count=0;

        while(index>=0 && index<=lenght){

        if(s.charAt(index)=='w'){
        count++;
        }
        index++;
        }

       System.out.println(count);
    }

}
```

Текст ошибки:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 14

Comment: `while (index < lenght) {`

Comment: Почему это работает?

Comment: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException как бы говорит сам за себя. Вы вышли за переделы диапазона 0..lenght - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (index < lenght) {
```

> Почему это работает?

Потому что индексы букв в строке находятся в диапазоне от `нуля` до `длина строки минус один`.